# HighChart Line Graph value from database

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to draw one page with HighChart. I took data from database. I wrote it with json_encode. I can see what my $xxx has value. Its json format. But my graph is not working. I think `var data = <?php echo json_encode($xxx); ?>` doesnt work and return valur. Where do I mistake?

Here is my php code for database value:

```
<?php
$var = "SELECT SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,1,4) AS year,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,6,2) AS month,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,9,2) AS day,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,12,2) AS saat,SUBSTRING(KayitTarihi,15,2) AS dakika,Guc FROM Urun WHERE Date(KayitTarihi)=\"".$link_m."\"";

$result = $mysqli->query($var);

$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}

$no = 1;
$total_deger=count($data); 

foreach($data as $dat)
{
$xxx ="[Date.UTC(".$dat['year'].",".$dat['month'].",".$dat['day'].",".$dat['saat'].",".$dat['dakika'].",00),".$dat['Guc']."]";
if($no < $total_deger)
{
    echo ",";
}
echo json_encode($xxx);
}


//free memory associated with result
$result->close();


//close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

And here is my highchart script:

```
<script>

$(function () {

var data = <?php echo $xxx; ?>;

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: [data]
                }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Edit: I edited json format. When I write just echo. Its just see one value.
Edit2: I have 9 value. My output is:

```
,,,,,,,,[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,10,28,00),0]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,14,25,00),0]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,14,25,00),0]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,14,27,00),17]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,32,00),54]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,32,00),54]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,33,00),93]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,33,00),34]
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,34,00),34]
```

But when ı read docs for highchart my value must be

```
([
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,10,28,00),0],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,14,25,00),0],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,14,25,00),0],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,14,27,00),17],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,32,00),54],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,32,00),54],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,33,00),93],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,33,00),34],
[Date.UTC(2016,11,15,18,34,00),34]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in quotes

```
var data = "<?php echo json_encode($xxx); ?>"
```

You should see this as an error in the console

Also you arent concatenating correctly. This means every time the loop runs you are overwriting the last entry stored in `$xxx`

```
$xxx = "[Date.UTC(".$dat['year'].",".$dat['month'].",".$dat['day'].",".$dat['saat'].",".$dat['dakika'].",00),".$dat['Guc']."]";
```

should be

```
$xxx .= "[Date.UTC(".$dat['year'].",".$dat['month'].",".$dat['day'].",".$dat['saat'].",".$dat['dakika'].",00),".$dat['Guc']."]";
```

Finally, change your loop to work like this

```
$xxx = '';

foreach($data as $dat){

    // if not a blank string i.e. something added, add a comma to the end read for the next concatenation
    if($xxx != '') $xxx .= ",";

    // concatenate
    $xxx .= "[Date.UTC(".$dat['year'].",".$dat['month'].",".$dat['day'].",".$dat['saat'].",".$dat['dakika'].",00),".$dat['Guc']."]";
}

// if not blank string, echo
if($xxx != ''){
    echo json_encode($xxx);    
}
```

Comment: My chart is still not working. I think my value should like ?([
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],]); but my value is: ,,,,,,,,,,[Date.UTC(2016,11,03,08,18,00),12][Date.UTC(2016,11,03,08,32,00),12][Date.UTC(2016,11,03,08,32,00),12]